# How can I disable the table tr when one is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to disable the tr when I click on the edit button.After completing the editing we have to enable it.The problem i can edit more than one files when one is selected.How can I do this?
My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lnkEdit').click(function () {
        $('#myTable tbody:first').append('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEItem"/></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEStatus"/></td><td><input type="button" value="Save" id="btnESave"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnECancel"/></td></tr>');
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```

Demo is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7WF/)

Comment: You mean other table rows must be disabled when one row is being edited?

Comment: @Harry- yes..you are right

Comment: add an id to the tr you append, then test in the click handler if it it exists

Comment: Ok, in that case why not have a `isEditing` flag and check it while another Edit link is being clicked?

Comment: @Harry- ya..i am trying to do that.But I can't get the id of other to check

Comment: @NithinViswanathan: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Zc7WF/1/) mate. If it fits your need, I will add it as answer.

Comment: @Harry- yes man.. But a single change is there, i dn't want error message can i do this like .attr('disabled',true);

Comment: @NithinViswanathan: I don't think links have a disabled attribute. If you wish, we can just do nothing when it is clicked (or for visual cue, change the color)

Comment: @Harry- ok then.. post it

Comment: Can I ask why you have too many `td` elements, one extra, in the 'editing' state? Is that deliberate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `isEditing` flag, check if it is set (another record is being edited) whenever a Edit link is clicked and perform the required action based on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isEditing = false;
    $('.lnkEdit').click(function () {
        if(!isEditing){
            $('#myTable tbody:first').append('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEItem"/></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEStatus"/></td><td><input type="button" value="Save" id="btnESave"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnECancel"/></td></tr>');
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            isEditing = true;
        }
        else{
            alert("Another row is being edited");
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:**

1. Remember to reset the `isEditing` flag when the `Save` or `Cancel` button is clicked.
2. For visual-cue, we can probably change the color of the other Edit links (to say, gray) when one Edit is being performed) and do away with the alert message.

Comment: Add this `$('.lnkEdit').css('color','gray');` within the `if` loop to change color of other Edit links when one is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

```
 $('.lnkEdit').click(function () {
        $('#myTable tr').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        });
        $('#myTable tbody:first').append('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEItem"/></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEStatus"/></td><td><input type="button" value="Save" id="btnESave"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnECancel"/></td></tr>');
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7WF/2/)

Comment: I think you are missed the demo

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.. hiding siblings of the parents, before you start appending

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lnkEdit').click(function () {
         $(this).parent().parent().siblings().hide(1000);
        $('#myTable tbody:first').append('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEItem"/></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEStatus"/></td><td><input type="button" value="Save" id="btnESave"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnECancel"/></td></tr>');
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: You are trying to hide that table.. I want to disable it
$(this).parent().parent().siblings().attr('disable',true);

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest the following:

```
/* we're replacing HTML contents, so using 'on()', rather than
   re-binding click-handlers: */
$('#myTable').on('click', 'a.lnkEdit:not(".disabled")', function(){
    // caching objects that might be used repeatedly:
    var self = $(this),
        origRow = self.closest('tr'),
        table = origRow.closest('table'),
        row = origRow.clone(),
    // creating a basic button to allow for creation of others:
        buttons = $(document.createElement('button')),
    // creating the two buttons (with their various properties):
        button1 = buttons.clone().text('Save').prop({
            'id' : 'btnESave'
        }),
        button2 = buttons.clone().text('Cancel').prop({
            'id' : 'btnECancel'
        });
    /* in the created/cloned row, emptying the first two cells,
       appending the text-input elements in the relevant cells: */
    row.find('td:lt(2)').empty().append(function(i){
        return $('<input />', {
            // setting relevant properties (edit to your taste, of course):
            'placeholder' : i === 0 ? 'Program' : 'Status',
            'type' : 'text',
            'id' : i === 0 ? 'txtEItem' : 'txtEStatus'
        });
    /* returning to the original selection with 'end()'
       finding the last 'td' element, emptying it and appending the
       previously-created buttons: */
    }).end().find('td:last-child').empty().append(button1, button2);
    // storing the original row in the jQuery data object:
    row.data('orig', origRow);
    // replacing the original row with the cloned/newly-created row:
    origRow.replaceWith(row);
    // adding the 'disabled' class to all 'a' elements currently in the table:
    table.find('a').addClass('disabled', true);
});

$('#myTable').on('click', 'button', function(){
    // caching the 'tr' since we're using it twice:
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    // removing the 'disabled' class-name from the 'a.disabled' elements:
    row.closest('table').find('a.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
    // replacing the current row with the storied original-row object:
    row.replaceWith(row.data('orig'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zc7WF/3/).

Note that, in the above, I've deliberately avoided adding an empty-cell to the start of the row and an extra-cell at the end, to maintain the table-structure (if this is a mistake, in your opinion, then obviously it can be easily adjusted to restore that empty `td`, but I can't think of a good reason to do so, since the `input`s would then not line up with the columns to which they *seem* (intuitively) to relate).

Of course, the trick here, really is simply adding the class of `disabled` to the `a` elements while editing is enabled for one `tr`, and using the selector (passed to `on()` to restrict the editing-trigger to only those `a` elements that *do not have* the `disabled` class: `a.lnkEdit:not(".disabled")`.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).
- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).